# The reference of the foreign key says the table doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I created 3 tables and even though all three tables exist and the columns have the same type it still says the "referenced table is invalid".

What should I do?

Note that in the database the three tables are in 3 separate SQL files.

```
CREATE TABLE user1(
    uid int identity ,
    primary key (uid),
    uname nvarchar(30) not null
)
CREATE TABLE forum1 (
    fname int identity ,
    primary key (fname),
    topic nvarchar(50) not null ,
    creatdata image  
)
CREATE TABLE message1(
    mid int not null ,
    Primary Key (mid),
    parentMsgId int not null,
    title nvarchar (50) not null,
    body nvarchar(50) not null,
    createData image not null,
    fname int ,
    creatorId int not null,
    Foreign Key (fname) references forum1(fname),
    Foreign Key (creatorId) references user1(uid),
    Foreign Key (mid) references message1(parentMsgId)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not mysql question

Comment: You use SQL Server aka MS SQL, not MySQL

Comment: Try with *dbo.forum1* and *dbo.user1*

Comment: You must receive another error message. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fd13a5176f49eac3b29ce13ef763729 PS. Shown error message text is not produced by SQL Server...

Comment: But another than what?   @pink-cat did not mention the error that was give, just some description about .....?

Comment: Also, need a 'close because of missing the complete error message'....

Comment: And a 'close because of adding an image with no extra info'.

Comment: The error could have been in the image, but it is not... , see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXEpS.png

Comment: `creatdata image` NO NO NO NO ON! That datatype has been deprecated for almost 20 years. Use varbinary.

Comment: You say you have created 3 tables, but then you say you are getting an error creating a table? Which is it? The images shows only 2 tables created? Are you running the create scripts as one batch or 3? And have you actually attempted to run the 3rd create script? Or are you just showing the editor errors? SSMS doesn't always update its cache very fast, so its errors can often be ignored.

Comment: Also pretty sure `Foreign Key (mid) references message1(parentMsgId)` should be the other way around i.e. `Foreign Key (parentMsgId) references message1(mid)` you are created a self reference, so must reference back to the PK.

Comment: Please add your sql server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is that you are trying to add self referencing foreign key to the table. You are trying to make your primary key a foreignkey by referencing to same table which is called self referencing foreign key. If your referenced column is unique you should be able to do this since your referencing column (mid) is primary key and it is by default unique and not null.

```
CREATE TABLE message1(
   mid int not null primary key ,   
   parentMsgId int not null unique,
   title nvarchar (50) not null,
   body nvarchar(50) not null,
   createData image not null,
   fname int ,
   creatorId int not null,
   Foreign Key (fname) references forum1(fname),
   Foreign Key (creatorId) references user1(uid),
   Foreign Key (mid) references message1(parentMsgId)
```

)

you can have self referencing foreign keys in your table. there is a limit of having such. The columns should have the same data type.  Try this code and check the possibility

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your foreign key reference in mid

```
CREATE TABLE user1(
    uid int identity ,
    primary key (uid),
    uname nvarchar(30) not null
);
CREATE TABLE forum1 (
    fname int identity ,
    primary key (fname),
    topic nvarchar(50) not null ,
    creatdata image  
);
CREATE TABLE message1(
    mid int not null ,
    parentMsgId int unique,
    title nvarchar (50) not null,
    body nvarchar(50) not null,
    createData image not null,
    fname int ,
    creatorId int not null,
    primary key (mid),
    Foreign Key (fname) references forum1(fname),
    Foreign Key (creatorId) references user1(uid),
    Foreign Key (mid) references message1(parentMsgId)
);
```

you are referencing a primary key (mid) to the current tables another column that is not unique

Comment: Pretty sure `Foreign Key (mid) references message1(parentMsgId)` should be the other way around i.e. `Foreign Key (parentMsgId) references message1(mid)`